# what happens to objects once application terminates

Tags: java, memory

In Java when I have an application running in appserver like glassfish, with my application deployed as EJB. When I undeploy EJB what happens to to sigletone classes that a loaded into memory. I understand until  I restart the container they are present there and can be garbage collected but I am not sure where and when it will happen, So if I deploy the ejb once again it may pick up the old objects from jvm,
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each deployed app is loaded with its own separate classloader. Since the classloader is part of a class's identity, the same class can be loaded multiple times (with different configuration) without the different instances interfering with each other.

This effectively isolates different applications within an app server from each other and even allows the same application to be run twice in parallel.

When an application is undeployed, all its objects (including the classloader and thus the classes themselves) will be garbage collected, if no references to them remain. Unfortunately, it can happen that references remain in some system class and prevent the garbage collection - this is called a [classloader leak](https://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java).

Comment: OK so when you say the classloader leak , does it mean it is a known problem, so although the application is undeployed there still some references remain and hence it can not be GC, and once I deply an app again my singletons will be re-used as opposed to recreated again?

Comment: @Loner shushman: No, the classes will not be reused (the redeployed app gets a new, separate classloader), but they will still occupy memory and eventually the app server will run out of memory after a number of redeployments.

Comment: OK so the classes will not be reused even if they are singletones? The reason I am asking is because we have the singletone classes, and we believe they still in the JVM and we impemented the shutdown mechanism to unload them from JVM, but you think although the objects are their they are not used(referenced once the application is redeployed)

Comment: Yes - from the point of view of the JVM, the classes will be different when the application is redeployed. BTW, if you're using EJBs and can use JEE 6, you should use the @Singleton annotation and let the app server manage the singletons.

Comment: thanks, we will be using @Singletone annotations, but the system which I inherited is writen under j2ee5 and does not support annotations, once we migrate to j2ee 6 we can rewrite it with the use of annotations.

Comment: but if as you say the classes going to be different, then what is the problem( except for the leak you mentioned of course), Why would i bother removing singletones manually,

Comment: ( or rely on container to remove them in j2ee 6 case) , whould not they be GC after the Application is undeployed. ( I know we written the special shutdown handlers for our singletons because as someoen told me if we undeploy the application, the singletones are still hanging in the memory, did they cater for the case of Memory leak? I see the problem with a leak is only if the Class contains some other classes which cause the leak , as described in the article? And what will be for

Comment: example for the case with say properties file, once they read and if I redepploy the application will they pick the new readings form the file if the file changed? I thought i need to restart the container?

Comment: @Loner shushman: yes, you're right - normally the singletons should be caught by regular GC and you don't have to shutdown them explicitly unless they need to do some cleanup e.g delete a file. And yes, if you redeploy the application, any property files read during application startup will be read in their then current version.

Comment: well ok, i will need to revisit the application and try to work out why did the developers in the past created some hooks to shutting down singletones? they reasoned that they need to remove it from jvm, but from what you saying now i dont need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is run at arbitrary times and you cannot control it. While Java's garbage collector can reuse old objects, I guess this is not the case. When you undeploy, the singleton gets destroyed. When you deploy, it creates a new one.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean by GC can reused old objects. I guess my question is : I expect my singleton to be destroyed once I undeploy the application but for some reason they singletone remains in the JVM because the JVM have not being restarted. And there was no specific command sent to this singletone to shut itself down